# How do I access core traits like StrExt when using #![no_std]?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write some Rust with `#![no_std]` set. I am trying to iterate over a `str` one character at a time; however none of the usual techniques seem to work. When I try to access the characters via a function provided by str, e.g. `for c in s.char_indices()` or `for c in s.chars()` I receive the error:

```
type &str does not implement any method in scope named ___
```

My understanding was that str was a part of `core` and therefore any traits it implements should be available in `no_std`. Is there a way to access this functionality, or an alternate way to iterate over a `str`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the trait to be able to call their methods, e.g.

```
#![no_std]
extern crate core;

use core::str::StrExt;

fn foo(s: &str) {
    for c in s.char_indices() {}
}
```

`core` also provides [an alternative prelude](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/prelude/index.html), which includes the functionality in `std::prelude` that is available in `core`. You can import it like `use core::prelude::*;`.

Comment: Are you cross-compiling?

Comment: yes, that is definitely the problem. Do I need the right version of core along with compatible libc?

Comment: You'll need a cross-compiled copy of `core`, yeah. I believe you can use [this unofficial publishing](https://crates.io/crates/core-nightly) of `core` with Cargo to cross compile more easily. Theoretically a libc isn't necessary, but you may need to use [`rlibc`](https://crates.io/crates/rlibc) (that's official) to provide some basic symbols like `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

Is `core::str::StrExt` automatically available though? I don't have the setup to compile something with `![no_std]`, but I got past a few hoops in the Playpen by adding

```
#![no_std]
#![feature(lang_items)]

extern crate core;
use core::str::StrExt;

fn main() {
    let s = "Hello";
    let mut cnt = 0u8; 

    for c in s.chars() {
        cnt += 1;
    }
}

#[lang = "stack_exhausted"] extern fn stack_exhausted() {}
#[lang = "eh_personality"] extern fn eh_personality() {}
#[lang = "panic_fmt"] fn panic_fmt() -> ! { loop {} }
```